# how to cite a foreign edition of a book with bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a common problem, but apparently there is no solution here.

I am citing a book. I use the common practice to cite the first original edition (in Italian), but I'd like my readers to also have the English version (or vice-versa). How to do it? I am using a standard bibtex package (chicago), and I am a bit lost...

I would like something like

> Milanovic B. (2016), Global inequality: a new approach for the age of globalization, Harvard University Press, Harvard (trad. it.
>   Ingiustizia globale, LUISS University Press, Roma 2017).

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas from https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43484/how-to-cite-sources-written-in-a-different-language-than-english? As for the technical issue, you can always use the `note` field, or include it in the `title` field.

Comment: `biblatex` has the `related` field that would come in very handy here. With BibTeX (and `chicago.bst` in particular) you will probably have to resort to the `note` field.

Comment: thanks, I will try the note. I have the additional problem that the bib file is created by Mendeley, but I will sort that out!